# How to skip to create button in php when the selected data is as same as $_SESSION?

Tags: php, sql, button, foreach, echo

Situation:

1. Select all data from the database
2. foreach to echo data using php

Expect:

1.if value in the array [empire_participation] is equal to $_Session[country], do not show the button id="joinBattle".

Result:

1. The button shows on the system whatever the value in array [empire_participation].

```php
<?php
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='dataTables-example'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>battle number</th><th>battle name</th><th>action</th></tr></thead> <tbody>";
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "colands";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, empire_participation FROM battle_field Group by id");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
      if($row["empire_participation"]==$_SESSION["country"]){
          break;
      }
?>
        <tr>
            <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>
                <?PHP echo $row["id"] ?>
            </td>
            <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>
                <?PHP echo $row["name"] ?>
            </td>
            
            <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>
                <button id="joinBattle" ng-show="<?php echo $row_['empire_participation'] ?>" onclick="joinBattle(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)">joinbattle</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?PHP

    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Clearly `$row["empire_participation"]==$_SESSION["country"]` is never evaluated as `true`. Have you tried dumping the values to see what they contain? Furthermore, what you're describing needs `continue`, not `break`. Breaking stops the loop entirely, while continuing only skips the current iteration.

Comment: I don't see a `start_session()` call?

Comment: $_SESSION["country"] is exits as the project is large so I quote the main parts to ask.

And I sure that $row["empire_participation"] includes the country name related to $_SESSION["country"]

Comment: Something you think you're sure about can still backfire in certain ways. Use `var_dump` on both values and identify the difference.